# How to set DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 from .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a working `Dockerfile` that requires execution with `BuildKit` support.

Question: how can I build the dockerfile from `gitlab-ci` and set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` globally?

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
    image: docker:20
    
    variables:
      DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    
    services:
      - docker:dind

    build:  
      script:
        - docker build .
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
    FROM maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11 as dependencies
    COPY pom.xml .
    COPY src src
    RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn package
```

Answer (score 4):

Gitlab runs inside a linux (native or container), so I suggest you to change `.gitlab-ci.yml` as follow:

```yaml
image: docker:20

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

build:  
  script:
    - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
```

Answer (score 4):

An other way is to create an environment variable as such:

```
image: docker:20

variables:
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1

# …
```

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/